Combining percentages to estimate new percentage
I am trying to estimate the proportion of the true freshman cohort (first-time, full-time, degree-seeking) who declared an undergraduate-level college major in their first year of college by their home state of residence. So, for example: For students who graduated from high school in state X and attended college that next year, what percentage of those students were full-time degree-seeking students and declared the desired college major in question. I do not have these data directly, but have pieces of these data that I might be able to construct an estimate. Here are the available data:

The number of the total undergraduate cohort (all incoming undergraduates)
The number of incoming full-time, first-time, degree-seeking undergraduate students
The number of first-time degree-seeking undergraduate students who graduated high school in the last 12 months (so, basically first-time here as well) by their state of residence when they were accepted
The number of full-time, first-year, degree-seeking undergraduate students who declared the major in question.

As you can see, there are some troubles with the types of students involved with each data source. Source 3 does not have degree-seeking in the counts, whereas Source 4 does. Does anyone have any information about how I might be able to meaningfully combine these data to create the estimate in question? I'm okay with assuming that the distribution of home states for entering true freshman are the same between the overall cohort and the cohort for the college major, as well as potentially other assumptions you all may see I may need to make.

Are you conflating numbers with percentages? Your title suggests one analysis while your data description suggests another. If you have a bundle of marginal percentages -- i.e., breakdowns of a sample into comprehensive and mutually exclusive buckets (like the percent of a population by age, income or gender breaks which sum to 100%) -- then a rough estimate of your objective can be obtained using iterative proportional fitting (IPF). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterative_proportional_fitting
